# What is the order of $3\pmod{3215}$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

To find the order we are finding the smallest $k$ such that $3^k \equiv 1\pmod {3215}$. Since the $gcd(3215, 3)=1$ we have that $3^{\phi (3215)} \equiv 1\pmod {3215}$.

Now i've found $3^{\phi (3215)} = 2568$. And it is true, that $3^{2568} \equiv 1\pmod {3215}$ however, this is not the smallest such $k$.

How do i find the smallest $k$ such that $3^k \equiv 1\pmod {3215}$ instead of just any $k$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the *Chinese remainder theorem*: from
$$\mathbf Z/3215\mathbf Z\simeq \mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/643\mathbf ,$$
you have to find the order of $3$ modulo $5$ (4) and its order modulo $643$.

As $643$ is prime, the latter is a divisor of $\varphi(643)=642=2\cdot3\cdot 107$.
Clearly the order of $3$ is not $2$, nor $3$ (too small), nor $6$, because it would mean $3^6=644$. Now $3^6=27^2$ has $1$ as last digit…

So we can try $107$, using the *fast exponentiation algorithm*:
$$\begin{array}{c ll}
n & x_n^2& P \cr
\hline
107&3&3 \cr
53&9&3\times 9=27\cr
26&81&27\cr
13& 81^2\equiv131& 27\times 131\equiv322\cr
6&131^2\equiv 443&322\cr
3&443^2\equiv134&322\times134\equiv 67\cr
1&134^2\equiv595&67\cdot595\equiv 642\equiv \color{red}{-1}\cr
\hline
\end{array}$$
Thus  we see $3$ has order $2\times 107$ modulo $643$, hence its order modulo $3215$ is $\operatorname{lcm}(2\times107,4)=428$.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest $k$ will necessarily divide $2568$ by [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) (the collection of numbers relatively prime to $3215$ form a group under multiplication modulo $3215$).  You can enumerate the possilibities for this $k$ knowing that $2568 = 2^3 \times 3 \times 107$.  I don't believe there's any way of knowing which divisor this $k$ will be without essentially brute-forcing.

Comment: I have been given the solution, which is 428. How do I use the fact that $2568=23×3×107$ to find 428?

Comment: @J.Doe Enumerate the divisors $d_i$ of $2568$, and check whether $3^d\equiv 1 \pmod {3215}$. Start from the lowest one, obviously, that way you can work your way up and stop once you reach $1$.